# How do I determine the command string eclipse uses to launch my java program?

Tags: java, eclipse, classpath

I've got a simple java program, socket, AWT and jUnit  dependencies.

I've built it in eclipse and when I run/debug it from eclipse it works.

When I launch it from the command line I get an error saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I'm guessing it's due to not finding one of the required dependencies in the classpath.

Given that launching from eclipse works, Is there a way of determining what command line eclipse uses to launch the same program?

Comment: How are you launching it from the command line? `java -jar myjar` or just plain `java myclass`?

Comment: What platform are you running on?

Comment: Have you looked at the list of dependencies in your Eclipse project? You should specify the same list of dependencies when calling your java program on the command line.

Comment: You need the same dependencies on the command line you have defined in your project's build path settings (minus compile-time-only requirements).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like your classpath isn't set appropriately when you try to run via the command line. You can easily export the command Eclipse uses by doing this:

1. Run your application and go to your Debug perspective
2. In the process viewer, there should be an entry for the app you've just executed
3. Right-click the row that mentions java.exe or javaw.exe
4. Select Properties
5. In the dialog that pops up you'll see the Command Line which includes all classpath entries and arguments

Comment: can you explain what process viewer is?  I looked in the Windows Task manager but didn't see the command line

Comment: when you're in the Eclipse Debug perspective, there will be a view called "Debug" that shows the process tree (there will be a root for the whole application and beneath that root it'll show all the running threads within the app). If you don't see that panel, select "Window" then "Show View" then "Debug" in eclipse when you're in the debug perspective.

Comment: Ahh, you're right!  I was able to copy that almost verbatim to the command line.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The classpath that Eclipse will use should be visible in your project's properties dialog...

Or, on a Unix-like system, you can cheat, with something like (Linux/Fedora) `ps axww | grep java` to peek around for the actual command-line.

On Linux, specifically, `/proc/`*pid*`/cmdline` will give the entire command-line (split with '\0' chars, so it may look run-together if you just `cat` the file) and `/proc/`*pid*`/environ` will show environment variables, if you need to peek at them, as well. (e.g. `CLASSPATH` environment variable)

Comment: Thanks for the tip on getting the command line for any linux process, I didn't know that before now.

Comment: if you're just poking around in the shell, you can `cat -v /proc/$PID/cmdline` to see the `'\0'` chars as "`^@`" strings, makes it a bit easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking 2 different questions here.

You can check your Java project's classpath by right clicking on the project name, and left clicking on the Properties option at the bottom.

On the Properties dialog, left clicking on the Java Build Path brings up the build path dialog.

If you want to determine the Eclipse command line string, you look at the Run Configurations.  On the menu, left click on Run, then left click on Run Configurations.  Under Java Application, you should find the run configuration for your project.  The Arguments tab shows you how Eclipse starts your Java project.